# How to stub a module method inside a controller with Mocha

Tags: ruby, module, sinatra, stub, ruby-mocha

I have a Sinatra app like this:

my_module.rb

```
module MyModule
  def my_method
    "yay"
  end
end
```

app.rb

```
get "/my_module" do 
  puts my_method
end
```

I'm trying to stub `my_method` on a test with `Minitest` and `mocha`.

```
def test_my_method
  MyModule.stubs(:my_method).returns("stubbed")
  get "/my_module"
end
```

But this don't seems to work, because the original method is still called. Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out two different ways to achieve this.

**1) Using [stub any instance gem](https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance).**

With this gem I could stub any instace of `Sinatra::Application`. So the solution looks like this:

```
def test_my_method
  Sinatra::Application.stub_any_instance(:my_method, "stubbed") do
    get "/my_module"
    # => stubbed
  end
end
```

**2) Using `mocha`'s [any_instance](https://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ClassMethods.html#any_instance-instance_method).**

This solution follows the same principle. Just using `mocha`s methods.

```
def test_my_method
  Sinatra::Application.any_instance.stubs(:my_method).returns("stubbed")
  get "/my_module"
  # => stubbed
end
```